# Get local notification's body text or identifier in AppDelegate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, unnotificationrequest

I want to access my application data in AppDelegate.swift whenever the app receives an action response. I was trying to use the

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == "check" {
        //do something to the app's data
    }

    completionHandler()

}
```

method, but I can't locate the data because I can't get the notification's identifier nor its body text. Could somebody help me on that? Thank you guys so much.

More Code:

```
//Setting content of the notification
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Scheduled Task"
content.body = taskDescriptionTextField.text!
content.badge = 1
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.categoryIdentifier = "alertCategory"
//Setting time for notification trigger
let date = datePicker.date
let dateCompenents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateCompenents, repeats: false)
//Adding Request
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: taskDescriptionTextField.text!, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: perhaps you missed out on something while implementing it. Please put up some more code.

Comment: thx for helping. I don't know how to get the identifier or the body content of the notification by calling the method didReceive response... Is there any way that I can send those data from the other ViewController to AppDelegate? More codes from ViewController below.

Comment: might look into this tut:- http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/
It covers all the basic stuff.

Comment: your settings for notification looks fine.. can you tell me again what do you want to do in the didReceive block?

Comment: I want to get the content.body text or the identifier of the UNNotificationRequest

Comment: In the link you gave me, it cannot edit or delete a specific item. For my app, I would like to edit or delete a specific, single item which requests the local notification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("original identifier was : \(response.notification.request.identifier)")
    print("original body was : \(response.notification.request.content.body)")
    print("Tapped in notification")
}
```

Basically what it is, is that you get a `UNNotificationResponse` instance back. That object has two properties.

- `var actionIdentifier: String`
- `var notification: UNNotification` <-- You need to use this one.

Also a very very good tutorial for UNUserNotification framework can be found [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250)

---

You only use the `actionIdenfier` if you want to find out which action did the user choose when they were presented a notification (Did they just just tap on it?! Did they just dismiss it?! Or did they select on a customAction?!)

// From Apple documentation: the action identifier that the user can chose from:

> ```
> * UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier if the user dismissed the notification
> * UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier if the user opened the application from the notification
> * the identifier for a registered UNNotificationAction for other actions
> ```

What it means is, you can use to do something like:

```
switch actionIdentifier {
case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier: // Notification was dismissed by user
    // Do something
    completionHandler()
case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier: // App was opened from notification
    // Do something
    completionHandler()
    // Do something else
case customAction:
    completionHandler()   
default:
    completionHandler()
}
```

To create custom actions you must:

- create an action inside a category
- register the category

For more information see this moment from [WWDC 2016 Advance Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/?time=1330)